# My new laptop is using 100% Disk despite all the tests I have done to detect the issue

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I recently bought a Dell Inspiron 5559 i5

and Since I've bought it I experienced Disk Issues

I get Write / Read speed in KB's or 1-2 MB's if I'm lucky

I did Various tests including

- Windows Default Scan
- HDD Sentinel
- Defragement and other 3rd party applications

But No luck still 
I'm getting no issues while playing some high end games or anything 
But other than that it literally goes 100% even if I'm watching a movie or surfing through my index / explorer .

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9k5MnPy.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/z3HdpMd.png]

Comment: Your lack of free space on all 3 drives doesn't help ...

Answer (score 0):

David's comment is absolutely right, however seeing as it's a laptop and will therefore have a battery, the following is worth a try:

Press the Windows key and "R" to open a run dialog box.

In the dialog box type devmgmt.msc then press ENTER to open the Device Manager.

Expand DISK DRIVES and you should see your hard drive.

Right-click on your hard drive and click PROPERTIES.

Under the POLICIES tab check to make sure all of the check boxes are checked.

This encourages Windows to make full use of the disk's speed by removing the disk protection fail-safes. I do the same with my machine but the important think to note is that you **must allow your laptop to shutdown/sleep itself** - if you ever 'kill the power' by pulling out the battery or holding the power button down there is a risk of data loss/corruption.

If you don't notice a difference in speed I suggest reversing these steps and looking at freeing some space up on your drive or even replacing it with an SSD.

Comment: The option to "Turn off Windows Write-Cache Bugger-Flushing on the Device" is disabled the other write-chaching one is enabled

Should I enable Both?

And Yes I do shut my Laptop like that but rarely


and I'm also working on freeing up the space , I can decrease it by 200 GB I'm pretty sure , but will that help massively or just will be a regret ?

Answer (score 0):

The [data from taskmanager come from the disk controller](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis#time=06m55s) (*Microsoft explained it in the video at 6m55 seconds*). The disk controller tells Windows that the drive is busy and Windows displays it in the taskmanager graph. This happens when the disk should read data from different locations on disk and here the rotating parts of the HDD cause the slowdown-

The best option to prevent this is to use a SSD and not a traditional HDD.